# Use Windows Runtime API in ASP.NET WebForm

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, windows-runtime

I have a `Windows Runtime` library for data encryption/decryption, which is consumed by a Windows store app. Now I am trying to expose the same  functionalities from an ASP.NET (v4.6) application.

I don't want to rewrite the data encryption/decryption code in classic .NET Framework. So I follow the [steps outlined here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-winrt-apis-from-desktop-applications) to use those Windows Runtime APIs in the ASP.NET application.

The steps are quite simple, just open the *.csproj* file in notepad and add this line to *PropertyGroup*,

```
<TargetPlatformVersion>8.1</TargetPlatformVersion>
```

then I can reference **Windows.winmd** and **System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll**, which contain all the types I will use.

## *The code to reproduce the issue*

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer buffer = Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.DecodeFromBase64String("U7WfTv43ThVoze8cBkRyu/OogTjzEHvyjJrO5KRusNaT9BZWCJ4BvIFxbjLmpd7F");
    }
}
```

## *The error:*

> System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))

**Also tried...**

I repeated the same steps in a Console application (also v4.6), the code runs smoothly, I can use `IBuffer` in Console, but why isn't it working in ASP.NET?